# Do I need to add a ground to this recycled appliance ac to usb converter?

Tags: usb, adapter

I found a lamp someone had thrown out and took it apart for components. It had an AC to USB adapter. Originally it had a 3 prong plug and was connected internally to various components and a grounding bar on the lamp.

The adapter did not have the ground wire does it need one?

It seems as though everything on the outer shell is plastic.

[image]

Comment: It's a random bit of electronics with no spec, no provenance and no schematic and, it has no guarantee that it is safe or even works. Throw it away back where you found it. Better still, dispose of it with respect to the environment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, seems like such a waste but you’re probably right. I can probably still use the usb shield for arruino projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power supplies that don't have a ground should be double insulated (And usually these are marked with a [double square](https://www.cui.com/blog/class-2-vs-class-ii-power-supplies)). However, I would be a little bit cautious if using such supplies as some of the cheaper supplies have regulatory markings but they are don't actually carry a certification (or have gone through a certification process).

Comment: Also of course Pari has removed the double insulation by taking it out of the device. I believe USB shields are typically grounded.

Comment: Ok ok thanks for your replies, basically I should probably just leave it and not try to hook it up then.

Comment: It just depends on how much you trust the supply and how willing you are to check the certifications on that supply.